# Являются ли части предложения однородными? Нужна или не нужна между ними запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

*− Идти сейчас? Ох, неужели я перепутал время?

− Нет-нет, тут другое! − засмеялся дедок. − Дело в том, что скоро к нам приедет директор **(,) и** он захочет вас видеть.*
Допустим ли вариант без запятой? <Дело в том, что скоро к нам приедет директор; дело в том, что он захочет вас видеть.> Обе части выполняют одну и ту же функцию: и объясняют, почему первый говоривший ничего не перепутал, и рассказывают, в чем же дело. При всем при этом сохраняется жгучее желание поставить запятую. Как быть? Помогите, пожалуйста, определиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте поставим запятую и попробуем объяснить свой выбор:

***Дело в том, что скоро к нам приедет директор, и он захочет вас видеть.***

Выражение «дело в том, что» является устойчивым, его называют межфразовой скрепой. Оно указывает **на причинно-следственную связь событий**, имеющих место ранее, например: Я не смогу сегодня прийти. Дело в том, что мне надо работать. Или: Я не смогу сегодня прийти, потому что мне надо работать. https://rrepetitor.ru/coma/delo-v-tom-chto-znaki-prepinaniya/

Формально кажется, что в приведенном предложении придаточные однородные: *Дело в том, что скоро к нам приедет директор(,) и **(что)** он захочет вас видеть.* Но в действительности, с точки зрения семантики, они **неоднородны.**

События, которые они обозначают, **не являются независимыми, их нельзя произнести с перечислительной интонацией.** Директор "не потом захочет", а уже сейчас (до своего приезда) хочет их видеть, и они должны быть не месте, когда он приедет.

Следовательно, придаточные неоднородные, запятая **ставится.**

Answer (score 0):

Запятая ставится по [этому правилу (пункт 1, примечание)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133), то есть при подлежащем — личном местоимении во втором предложении, которое относится к подлежащему первого предложения. В правиле напрямую не говорится, что это правило работает несмотря на общее сочетание, но этот вывод можно сделать на основании примеров (спасибо Розенталю, за то что он держит в тонусе и позволяет додумывать некоторые моменты):

> Вдали по-прежнему машет крыльями мельница, и всё ещё она похожа на маленького человечка, размахивающего руками (Ч.).
> Ты всегда был строг ко мне, и ты был справедлив (Т.).